# Run method after startup finishes

Tags: java, spring, spring-shell

I am creating a command line application in java using Spring-shell.  I want to implement auto update feature. I want to run the "check for update" code as soon as Spring-shell finish its initialisation. i.e after it prints welcome and version note.

Is there a way to do that?  How can i hook a piece of code at that point?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bean that implements [ApplicationListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html#onApplicationEvent-E-)

take a look at the event documentation [7.15.2 Standard and Custom Events](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events)

Comment: will this work for Spring-shell too.  I want to run the update code specifically after Spring shell Prints Banner and welcome note.

Comment: I think so write listener for ContextEventRefresh and/or ContextEventStarted check if spring shell emit one

Comment: The ApplicationListener is firing before the Banner is being printed. Currently I found no easy way to do this in spring-shell, since the deciding places (eg. ```ExecutionStrategy``` within ```AbstractShell```) are hardcoded (```new SimpleExecutionStrategy()..```).

One place to look for is the ```PromptProvider```, but this is fired multiple times, so it is probably not fitting your usecase.

Is there a particular reason to not fire before the banner?